# Thermodynamic efficiency limit of solar cells instead of Shockley–Queisser limit

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

I am considering the efficiency limit of solar cells, at first, it occurs to me that there should be a thermodynamic efficiency limit and try to reduce the entropy production as much as possible, just like the Carnot cycle. But in the end, I find the popular theory of the efficiency limit of solar cells is [Shockley–Queisser limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley%E2%80%93Queisser_limit) which doesn't consider the entropy production at all. My question is:
Is there any theory that consider the entropy production in the solar cell?